# MarkLogic trigger declaration- What am I doing wrong in this?

Tags: triggers, marklogic

I am dabbling in MarkLogic and am not having an easy time of it. Recently I have been experimenting with triggers, and it has been going just as poorly. It was my hope that someone here could offer me some advice as to what exactly I am doing wrong here.

Following the MarkLogic Community tutorial at https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/triggers#id_66092 I named my database test, and listed it as its own triggers database. I then ran this query against the test database:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml"
import module namespace trgr="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/triggers" 
 at "/MarkLogic/triggers.xqy";

trgr:create-trigger("myTrigger", "Simple trigger example", 
  trgr:trigger-data-event(
  trgr:directory-scope("/myDir/", "1"),
  trgr:document-content("create"),
  trgr:post-commit()),
  trgr:trigger-module(xdmp:database("test"), "/modules/", "log.xqy"),
  fn:true(), xdmp:default-permissions() );
```

Which returned `14463004257041262559`, and I can confirm that this is the correct URI.

I then defined `/modules/log.xqy` as instructed using this query:

```
xquery version '1.0-ml';
(: evaluate this against the database specified 
in the trigger definition (test in this example)
:)
xdmp:document-insert("/modules/log.xqy", 
  text{ "
xquery version '1.0-ml';
import module namespace trgr='http://marklogic.com/xdmp/triggers' 
   at '/MarkLogic/triggers.xqy';

declare variable $trgr:uri as xs:string external;

xdmp:log(fn:concat('*****Document ', $trgr:uri, ' was created.*****'))"
}, xdmp:permission('app-user', 'execute'))
```

Which I then confirmed existed, and exactly matched the text between the quotation marks.

However, when I ran `xdmp:document-insert("/myDir/test.xml", <test/>)`, the document was created and nothing else happened. When I opened `ErrorLog.txt` the text it was supposed to append was not there.

Thinking it may have been that I was looking in the wrong place, I also added `fn:doc("/modules/log.xqy")`  so that it would show me if it ran, but inserting new documents into the correct directory never prompted any sort of action from the trigger.

I’m hoping that one of your number can show me what I am doing wrong, because this is rather frustrating. I await your aid.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with what you're doing.  In fact, I copied/pasted your commands and they ran perfectly except one minor typo: your first command is missing a semicolon on the first line.  But since you saw the created trigger I presume it didn't have that error when you ran it.  With that fixed and all commands run, I got this in my ErrorLog.txt after the last command ran: 2015-12-09 09:37:06.438 Info: TaskServer: *****Document /myDir/test.xml was created.*****

Comment: Are you running all these commands in qconsole against the "test" database?  You specify that you did on the first command, but not the second and third.

Comment: Yes, all three queries are being executed in the database named "test" and I can confirm that the last query is inserting new documents into that database, but the ErrorLog is never being changed.

Comment: @Sam Mefford If it works fine on your database then perhaps I didn't set up mine correctly. Do you have any ideas how I may have improperly configured the test database when I was creating it?

Comment: I tested it and it worked for me as well.  I just created a brand new database with all default values.  I created a **role** `test-role` and added a new **user** `test-user` to it (and replaced `app-user` with `test-role` in your code).

Comment: So how did you insert the document as "test-user?" So far I have only been able to execute queries from the qconsole, which requires logging in as an account with special privileges.

Comment: So I created a new database from scratch like you did and just used "app-user" rather than "test-user." I have absolutely no idea why this didn't work on the first database but you were both right - there is nothing wrong with the code posted by MarkLogic Community. Thank you both for your help, because without it I would still be trying to fix good code on a broken database.

Comment: Glad things are working for you now

Comment: Trying to fix good code is indeed a waste of time :-)

Answer (score 0):

You say you created `modules/log.xqy`, but the code refers to `/modules/log.xqy`. These two URIs are indeed different.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I fixed the typo above.